# HOW TO: Listener on ListPreference to change Google Map Mode?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to make the **ListPreference with key "map_mode"** set the actual map mode in my **MapActivity.java**. So that when I click "Satellite" for instance in the Preferences screen, it changes on the Map.

I have a ListPreference setup like this **settings.xml** (preference.xml):

```
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="settings"
        android:title="Settings" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="map_settings"
        android:summary="Enable or Disable Map Settings"
        android:title="Enable Map Settings" />

    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="Map"
        android:dependency="map_settings"
        android:entries="@array/mapMode"
        android:entryValues="@array/mapModeValues"
        android:key="map_mode"
        android:summary="Change the display of the map"
        android:title="Map Mode" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

The "map_mode" is reading array values from this **arrays.xml**:

```
<string-array name="mapMode">
    <item name="Map">Map</item>
    <item name="Satellite">Satellite</item>
    <item name="Traffic">Traffic</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="mapModeValues">
    <item name="Map">Map</item>
    <item name="Satellite">Satellite</item>
    <item name="Traffic">Traffic</item>
</string-array>
```

Thank you.

**This is PreferenceScreen. When user presses one of these options I want it to update the MapActivity.**

[image: PreferenceScreen][image: MapActivity]

Answer (score 0):

Have your `MapActivity` call `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`, then process the `SharedPreference` change in your `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.

Or, simply re-read and apply the preference in `onResume()`, since your `PreferenceActivity` and your `MapActivity` will not be on the screen at the same time.

Comment: How would I put this in code? If you are free can you quickly upload an example?

Comment: I can't get this to work. Tried what you said. Extra pointers please mate.

Comment: @Zukky: For somebody who cursed me (and the rest of SO) out in another edition of this question, you are very demanding. Perhaps if you behaved more civilly, you would have better results. That being said, here is a sample of reading preferences in `onResume()`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/Simple

Comment: I didn't curse mate. I posted the other one at nearly exactly the same time as you made that comment. Didn't mean to offend. Checking it out right now

Comment: I've added images, I've been stuck on this all day lol. Can someone please give me indication.

Comment: I finally understand you mate! I tried to learn all I could about "SharedPreferences" - CommonsWare you are a f'in genius.

Comment: Still not working -___-. Someone some assistance. How can I change it?

Comment: Worked it out. After a long and lengthy process it is done. Contact me if you want to know.